# The parameter Listen : False of Provider package doesn't work ? Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

Listen:False
I'm trying to stop rebuild LandingUser Widget but it doesn't work wiht listen : false . And if it keep it rebuilding I faces another issue I explained it // in the code below .

**LandingUser class**

```
class LandingUser extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingUser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Landing User Rebuild ----------");
    final auth = Provider.of<AuthService?>(context , listen: false); // false not working
    print(auth);
    return StreamBuilder<MyUser?>(  
      stream: auth!.onChangeStateUser,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {  
        print(snapshot.hasData);    
        print(snapshot);
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) { 
          MyUser? user = snapshot.data;  
          print("user   $user");   
          if (user == null) {
            return Scaffold(body: Text('test login rebuild'),); // LogingScreen();
          } else {
            return Scaffold(body: Text('test Not null User rebuild'),); // UserProfile();
          }
        }else{
          //if(user==null){return LoginScreen();} //without if .. CircularProgressIndicator don't stop because I used in Login Screen page TextFormFeild and when foucse the widget rebuild itself and start loading again cuz the widget rebuilt .. this is another issue _!_
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
      
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Root widget main :**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Main rebulided");
    return Provider<AuthService?>.value(
      value: AuthService(),
      child: MaterialApp(
       //.......

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**auth!.onChangeStateUser Stream getter:**

```
@override
  Stream<MyUser?>? get onChangeStateUser => _auth.authStateChanges().map((event) => _userFromFirebase(event));
```

**_userFromFirebase Private Func :**

```
MyUser? _userFromFirebase(User? user) {
   if (user == null) {
     return null;
   }
   return MyUser(uid: user.uid);
 }
```

*Thanks in advance*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Provider.of<AuthService?>(context , listen: false);
```

The above code means the widget it's being used in will not rebuilt when the value of `AuthService` changes.

It does not mean your widget will not be rebuilt when something else like the `auth!.onChangeStateUser` stream is being used in a `StreamBuilder`.

So while the value of `AuthService` isn't changing, the stream from the instance of `AuthService` is changing and that is what is causing the rebuilds.

Comment: I think I have to close the stream after I got the vale from it . And I did it like a method and I called it when the connection was acitve ,but if the value change again the stream didn't initialized by itself .